# how to make ImageView visible by timer

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, timer, android-viewpager

I have a problem. I have an Activity with ViewPager which has 3 Fragments (3 Pages).

My first Fragment/Page has an ImageView. I used this code below in my MainActivity.java document to make that ImageView visible by timer but it works not as I expected. When i want to go to next page by scrolling and touch the screen ImageView dissapear.

```
final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.earth);
mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
       mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}}, 5000);
```

**My QUESTIONS**: How to start timer when Page will be full screen cause as I said when i want to go to next page by scrolling and touch the screen (move page a little bit) ImageView dissapear.?! In my code as i understand final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.earth); is part of my Activity. How to make that ImageView part of concrete page?!

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you will have to clarify a little better what you are saying in order to get a response.  Could you be clearer?

Comment: Sorry for my English but what exactly you dont understand? I updated my post a little bit. Can you check it again and do you have any ideas?!